# Laravel multiple keywords search on multi table with operator AND/OR

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have an advanced search form that filter results from mySql database. There is one part which is a keyword search that should match any text fields on all related tables.

This is the said search form code.

```
<form action="/search" method="POST">
   Keyword: <input type="text" name="keyword">
   Matching: <input type="radio" name="keywordControl" value="AND"> Match every words<br>
             <input type="radio" name="keywordControl" value="OR"> Match any words<br>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` INT,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(100),
  `lastName` VARCHAR(100),
  `email` VARCHAR(100),
  `address` VARCHAR(400)
);

CREATE TABLE `savedLinks` (
  `id` INT,
  `userId` INT,
  `linkName` VARCHAR(100),
  `linkURL` VARCHAR(400),
  `linkNote` VARCHAR(100),
);

CREATE TABLE `BlogEntry` (
  `id` INT,
  `userId` INT,
  `entryTitle` VARCHAR(100),
  `entryExcerpt` VARCHAR(100),
  `entryBody` TEXT,
);
```

What I need:

if I search by these parameters:

keyword: **naruto area51**

keywordControl: **AND**

I expect to see results that match both naruto and area51 across all tables.

However, what I can do is filter results on the same table. I manage to display results like

- "Mister **Naruto**", who has an address of "**Area51** lane..."
- Anyone who saved links that contain both "**Naruto**" and "**Area51**"
- Anyone who blogged about "**Naruto** running" and "**Area51**"

But I can't bring results like

- "Mister **Naruto**", who has blogged about "**Area51**"
- anyone who saved links about "**Naruto**", and blogged about "**Area51**"

Because those latter need to search across all tables.  This is my laravel eloquent code.

```php
$keyword = urldecode($request->input('keyword'));
$keywords = preg_split('/\s+/', $keyword, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$users = User::when(sizeof($keywords) > 0, function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
        foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
            if ($keywordControl == 'AND') {
                $query->whereRaw("CONCAT(firstName,lastName,email,address) LIKE ?", "%{$keyword}%");
            } else {
                $query->orWhereRaw("CONCAT(firstName,lastName,email,address) LIKE ?", "%{$keyword}%");
            }
        }
    });
})
->when(sizeof($keywords) > 0, function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
    $query->whereHas('savedLinks', function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
            foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
                if($keywordControl == 'AND'){
                    $query->whereRaw("CONCAT(linkName,linkURL,linkNote) LIKE ?", "%{$keyword}%");
                } else {
                    $query->orWhereRaw("CONCAT(linkName,linkURL,linkNote) LIKE ?", "%{$keyword}%");
                }
            }
        });
    });
})
->when(sizeof($keywords) > 0, function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
    $query->whereHas('blogEntry', function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
            foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
                if($keywordControl=='AND') {
                    $query->whereRaw("CONCAT(entryTitle,entryExcerpt,entryBody) LIKE ?", "%{$keyword}%");
                } else {
                    $query->orWhereRaw("CONCAT(entryTitle,entryExcerpt,entryBody) LIKE ?", "%{$keyword}%");
                }
            }
        });
    });
})
->get();
```

What I have in my mind is that, or if I should create another table and concat all those text in the same field for search purpose only. I don't know if it's a good idea or not. Please guide me, thanks!

Comment: even if it did work, this would be extremely slow

Comment: Update: So I did create another table and concat all texts into single TEXT field. It works fast. Easy to write query. The only downside is it eat up some storage spaces, which I still have plenty more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define relationships for User, SavedLinks and Blogs? For this query, it's necessary that User has the correct relationships with the models in question:

```php
# User model
public function savedLinks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SavedLink::class, 'userId', 'id');
}

public function blogEntries()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BlogEntry::class, 'userId', 'id');
}
```

All your `when(...)` conditions are the same. This query could be rewritten to take that into account.

Also, `whereRaw()` accepts **3** parameters. If you check [it's definition](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L807), you'll see the following:

```php
/**
 * Add a raw where clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $sql
 * @param  mixed   $bindings
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @return $this
 */
public function whereRaw($sql, $bindings = [], $boolean = 'and')
{
    $this->wheres[] = ['type' => 'raw', 'sql' => $sql, 'boolean' => $boolean];
    $this->addBinding((array) $bindings, 'where');
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add a raw or where clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $sql
 * @param  mixed   $bindings
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|static
 */
public function orWhereRaw($sql, $bindings = [])
{
    return $this->whereRaw($sql, $bindings, 'or');
}
```

It also seems to me you should be using `orWhereHas`. You could use `empty()` instead of `sizeof()` and `unless()` ([it's just the opposite function](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.html#method_unless)) instead of `when()` to make things more readable too. With that in mind, your query can already be reduced to this, assumming `$keywordControl` is either AND or OR:

```php
$users = User::unless(empty($keywords), function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
        foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
            $query->whereRaw("CONCAT(firstName,lastName,email,address) LIKE ?", "%{$keyword}%", $keywordControl);
        }
    });
})
->orWhereHas('savedLinks', function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
        foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
            $query->whereRaw("CONCAT(linkName,linkURL,linkNote) LIKE ?", "%{$keyword}%", $keywordControl);
        }
    });
})
->orWhereHas('blogEntry', function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($keywords, $keywordControl) {
        foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
            $query->whereRaw("CONCAT(entryTitle,entryExcerpt,entryBody) LIKE ?", "%{$keyword}%", $keywordControl);
        }
    });
})
->get();
```

I don't know if concatenating things with whereRaw and then comparing that is faster than using where clauses for each attribute though.

```php
# Example 
->whereRaw("CONCAT(entryTitle,entryExcerpt,entryBody) LIKE ?", "%{$keyword}%", $keywordControl);
# vs
->where([
    ['entryTitle', 'like', "%{keyword}%", $keywordControl],
    ['entryExcerpt', 'like', "%{keyword}%", $keywordControl],
    ['entryBody', 'like', "%{keyword}%", $keywordControl],
])
# If someone could comment on this I'd be grateful.
```